# Duplication issue in Log::useDailyFiles

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to use Logger to log info on a daily basis.
Under a loop event, the log file catches output in the below fashion

`Log output1
Log output2
Log output2
Log output3
Log output3
Log output3`

and so on.
Any possible way to prevent this.
Laravel version - 5.4

Comment: There must be some mistake in your code, because it increments every loop. Can you post your code?

Comment: I am sure it is not an code issue, It might be as issue of attaching a new log handler and asking the old log handler to print it again. I read at github pages to register the log handler once during bootstrapping. But i am unsure how to do that

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14522   This might be of any help.